# How do i count how many strings occur in list and each column of another file?

Tags: r, string-comparison, overlap

I am looking for a way (preferably but not necessarily in R) to find the number of times items in a reference list also occur in a series of lists. I need to know the extent of overlap for each comparison between the reference list and another list.

So I have one list with a series of strings like this (first 4 lines):

```
A2345
A3545
A643636
A3255
```

Lets call that ListA.

I then have a tab delimited text file (file2) with several columns containing similar strings. Each column is a similar independent list:

```
A25325  A5634   A765436 A232
A3255   A35674  A5353   A474
A3453   A632        A5464   A863
A5543   A656        A8768   A684
```

I know a few ways in the shell to check for overlap between two lists, but I dont know a way to say: Take listA and for each column in another file count how many times strings from listA occur. For each column output the number of strings that are found in the column and in listA. 
So the issue is how to iterate over columns in a text file and output the amount of overlap.

In the example above the output would be: 1 0 0 0
Because A3255 appears in listA and in column 1 of file2
The output format isn't crucial, just some way to know how many overlaps occur in each file.

Thanks 
Sorry if a duplicate question, I searched but didn't see one already.

Answer (score 0):

If you read your tab delimited text file into a simple data.frame, you can use an `apply()` function :

```
listA <- c("A2345", "A3545", "A643636", "A3255")
listB <- data.frame(b1 = c("A25325", "A3255", "A3453", "A5543"),
                b2 = c("A5634", "A35674", "A632", "A656"),
                b3 = c("A765436", "A5353", "A5464", "A8768"),
                b4= c("A232", "A474", "A863", "A684"))

listB
#       b1     b2      b3   b4
# 1 A25325  A5634 A765436 A232
# 2  A3255 A35674   A5353 A474
# 3  A3453   A632   A5464 A863
# 4  A5543   A656   A8768 A684
```

then a simple `apply()` call should do the job :

```
apply(listB, 2, function(x) {sum(x %in% listA)})
b1 b2 b3 b4 
 1  0  0  0
```

The argument `MARGIN=2` in the apply() function will iterate the search over the columns. You can have a look here : https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/apply.html